# Zabbix agent status monitoring

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

What is the right way to monitor agent status? I want to be able to see whether agent is running or not. `agent.ping` item only shows if agent is *Up*, but it doesn't switch to *Down*. Simple check `icmpping`seems to behave the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to monitor `agent.ping` is via triggers, and for that item you would use the `nodata()` trigger function (the default template already does that.

The `icmpping` item actually returns 1 when the host is reachable via ICMP ping, and 0 when not (but that's not really monitoring the agent).

If you want to see up/down in the item itself, you could monitor agent TCP port (10050 by default) with item like `net.tcp.service` - but using a trigger on agent.ping would be the recommended way still.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of monitoring the port, you can have from version 2+ the internal Zabbix checks which stores the 0 and 1 values each time, not like agent.ping which only stores the value 1 (the main reason why you do not get a "Down" message).

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/internal

Key that you need is zabbix[host,agent,available] and the item type should be "Zabbix internal" instead of "Zabbix agent".